# Visual studio warning when using Qt connect

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5, visual-studio-2019

So I am using Visual Studio 2019 with Qt 5.12.2 C++. I made a very basic form ui like this:

```cpp
MyApp::MyApp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyApp::onConnectClicked);
}

void MyApp::onConnectClicked()
{
    ui.pushButton->setText("Clicked");
}
```

The program runs fine but at this line:

```cpp
    connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyApp::onConnectClicked);
```

Visual Studio keeps giving me this warning

```cpp
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26444  Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84).
```

Also this error:

```cpp
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  E2524   the argument to a feature-test macro must be a simple identifier    
at C:\Dev\5.12.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qcompilerdetection.h line 1349
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2020-04-08:**
Microsoft has fixed this.  The latest VS2019 release no longer issues a warning on every single use of Qt's connect().

I'm leaving the old answer in place below for people who cannot update for whatever reason.

Since you're using Qt the way it's intended, and since we can assume that Qt's authors know what they are doing, it is reasonable to assume that the warning is overzealous, can be gotten rid off without danger, and is not worth much effort.

The method I use to get rid of it is to cast the result of `connect()` to void, i.e.

```
(void)connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyApp::onConnectClicked);
```

The cast has no effect, but it clearly expresses that one intends to ignore the result, it is fairly unintrusive, and it makes the warning disappear.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the old answer there, we are stuck with an older VS2019 release for a while

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help, but a similar problem is under investigation from VS side:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520400/visual-studio-2019-with-qt-vs2019-detects-many-war.html

which is a duplicate of the following one:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520393/vs-2019-detects-many-false-warnings-while-vs2017-w.html

To make it short, they claim those warnings are false flags and one workaround proposed:

> If you reconfigure the project with VS2017 toolchain, clean and
>   regenerate the project, all these warnings will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, are you suggesting that I should downgrade my VS2019 to VS2017?